# Prevent duplicates on left join combined with inner join in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

Here's my sql. I can't filter out duplicates in the query if there are duplicate entries in the matches_times table

```
SELECT
  info.user_id,
  info.name,
  info.age,
  info.gender,
  DATE_FORMAT(likes.time, '%c/%e/%y') AS matchedTime,
  DATE_FORMAT(matches_times.proposed_time, '%b %d, %Y @ %h:%i %p') AS proposedTime,
    matches_times.agreed
FROM info
INNER JOIN likes
  ON info.user_id = likes.liked_user_id
  AND likes.user_id = ?
LEFT JOIN matches_times
  ON (info.user_id = matches_times.user_id_1 OR info.user_id = matches_times.user_id_2)
  AND (matches_times.user_id_1 = ? OR matches_times.user_id_2 = ?)
WHERE likes.liked_user_id IN (SELECT
  user_id
FROM likes
WHERE likes.liked_user_id = ?)
ORDER BY
    CASE 
      WHEN matches_times.proposed_time IS NULL THEN likes.time 
      WHEN matches_times.proposed_time IS NOT NULL THEN matches_times.proposed_time
    END DESC
```

The three tables are as follows:

#### likes

```
id(pk) | user_id | liked_user_id | timestamp
```

#### info

```
id(pk) | user_id | name | age | gender | timestamp
```

#### matches_times

```
id(pk) | user_id_1 | user_id_2 | proposed_time | agreed | timestamp
```

**EDIT:**

The problem is portrayed here

[image]

Comment: mysql or sql-server?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Kindly provide some sample data and expected result from that sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way is based ond the fact you could use a subselect with distinct ( o a equivalent view)

```
LEFT JOIN (

    select distinct user_id_1, user_id_2,  DATE_FORMAT(proposed_time, '%b %d, %Y @ %h:%i %p') as proposed_time
    from matches_times

) t  ON (info.user_id = t.user_id_1 OR info.user_id = t.user_id_2)
  AND (t.user_id_1 = ? OR t.user_id_2 = ?)
```

and in select refer to t.proposed_time

if you need  max you don't need  distinct but you need  group by eg:

```
LEFT JOIN (

    select  user_id_1, user_id_2,  max(DATE_FORMAT(proposed_time, '%b %d, %Y @ %h:%i %p')) as proposed_time
    from matches_times
    group by user_id_1, user_id_2

) t  ON (info.user_id = t.user_id_1 OR info.user_id = t.user_id_2)
  AND (t.user_id_1 = ? OR t.user_id_2 = ?)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm getting this error though `Unknown column 'matches_times.proposed_time' in 'field list'`

Comment: No error now, but still getting the same result as my pic. Am I missing something or am I just a dummy?

Comment: you have two diffrent proposed time so you you get two rows .. could be you need  the max or the min fo this  .. and then you get one row only

Comment: Can you provide an example? Not sure I follow 100%

Comment: @lazyboy78  answer updated .. hope  my answer is useful (at least)

Comment: Works like a charm, boss. You have officially restored my faith in this community as one that actually cares about helping its users. I learned something new today too. Thanks